# How to store stored procedure return value in a table or variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I have a stored procedure in which I want to store a value returned by another stored procedure how would I do it. I tried and googled, but couldn't succeed. My code is:

```
declare @t table (name varchar(100))      
declare @MprNum varchar(20)      
insert @t exec usp_GetNextInvoice 'MPRId','MPRNo','MPRMain'       
select @MprNum=name from @t
```

I also tried this:

```
create table #t(name varchar(100))
declare @MprNum varchar(20)
insert #t exec usp_GetNextInvoice 'MPRId','MPRNo','MPRMain'
select @MprNum=name from #t
```

But no success.

Comment: what does it mean by no success

Comment: How does `usp_GetNextInvoice` return that value, `return` or `select`? Please show relevant details of that stored procedure.

Comment: The value is returned by select statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO #t
    EXEC usp_GetNextInvoice 'MPRId','MPRNo','MPRMain'
```

Comment: just look at the question i have already tried it. it's not working.

Comment: When you say "it's not working" do you mean 1) You got an error message or 2) It executes successfully but you didn't get any data?

Comment: the procedure gives me this "STI-00001" but it is not inserted in the table #t

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to Output a result in to a variable ,script like below.

```
--Procedure :
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetNextInvoice 
@MPRId int,
@MprNum int OUTPUT
AS  

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @MprNum = MprNum
    FROM YourTable T
     WHERE T.MPRId = @MPRId

RETURN
GO

-- Execution step
DECLARE @Result int;
EXECUTE usp_GetNextInvoice 10, @MprNum = @Result OUTPUT;
SELECT @Result
```

If you wanted to Output a resultset in to a table,try with the below script

```
--Procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetNextInvoice 
@MPRId int
AS  

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT *
    FROM YourTable T
     WHERE T.MPRId = @MPRId

RETURN
GO

--execution step
CREATE TABLE #T
(Col1 ...  -- column count should match with the output of the procedure
 ....)
GO

INSERT INTO #T
EXEC usp_GetNextInvoice 10
```

Comment: i tried the table insertion but data is not inserted

Comment: no error is given. but the data is also not inserted in the table. gives message "0 rows effected"

Comment: are you getting resultset ,if you exexutiong the procedure with out the INSERT command.. ??  Can you provide your Stored procedure script also?

Comment: yes when i execute procedure it gives me this value "STI-00001"

Answer (score 0):

Is this statement return any row?

```
exec usp_GetNextInvoice 'MPRId','MPRNo','MPRMain'
```

Because code you tried is perfect....

Comment: Yes it returns this value "STI-00001"